# Redux Saga good example

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, redux-saga

I'm fairly new to Redux Saga, and I'm looking around for any repositories which have been written recently using React and Redux Saga to get a good idea of how an app should look/work. Most of the articles / videos etc appear to be quite old and still using Classes in React. I've done the obvious and looked on the Redux Saga site, however want a fully fledged app as an example.

Does anyone have a link to a repo with a good example of using Redux Saga, with tests etc that is recent?

Comment: _"old and still using Classes in React"_ - why do you victimize Classes in React? It hadnt been proven yet that hooks are any better than Classes. Furthermore - a lot of React devs complain about hooks readability (including me).

Comment: React classes are not that old and not deprecated yet. Also React Classes/hook have got very little to do with Redux + Saga.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/shinima/battle-city, This is a Nintendo FC's battle city remake in JS by a Chinese developer [Shinima](https://github.com/shinima), he is also one of the redux-saga's [core contributor](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/graphs/contributors). All the game logic is heavily leveraging Redux-Saga. The Readme and the source code comment is in Chinese, try to use Google translate if you need to understand some of the code comment. The core business logic in the sagas folder is pretty straightforward to follow though.